# How to drop all connections to a specific database without stopping the server?

Tags: postgresql, connections, session

I want to drop all connections (sessions) that are currently opened to a specific PostgreSQL database but without restarting the server or disconnecting connections to other databases.

How can I do that?

Comment: I read somewhere that you could use http://www.lowth.com/cutter/ to achive this.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Here is my answer to [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408156/how-to-drop-a-postgresql-database-if-there-are-active-connections-to-it/19884946#19884946) on StackOverflow.

Depending on your version of postgresql you might run into a bug, that makes `pg_stat_activity` to omit active connections from dropped users. These connections are also not shown inside pgAdminIII.

If you are doing automatic testing (in which you also create users) this might be a probable scenario.

In this case you need to revert to queries like:

```
 SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.procpid) 
 FROM pg_stat_get_activity(NULL::integer) 
 WHERE datid=(SELECT oid from pg_database where datname = 'your_database');
```

Comment: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "pg_stat_activity" (psql (9.6.1))

Comment: this does not work anymore....get the above error ^

Comment: This worked for me, @Szymon Guz's solution should be the accepted answer now: `select pg_terminate_backend(pid) from pg_stat_activity where datname='DB_NAME';`

Answer (score 156):

The query like this should help (assuming the database is named 'db'):

```
select pg_terminate_backend(pid) from pg_stat_activity where datname='db';
```

`pid` used to be called `procpid`, so if you're using a version of postgres older than 9.2 you could try the following:

```
select pg_terminate_backend(procpid) from pg_stat_activity where datname='db';
```

However you have to be a superuser to disconnect other users.

It might also be useful to `REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE FROM PUBLIC` or something similar, and then `GRANT` it afterward.

Comment: This is the working answer May 2021

Comment: This should be accept as correct answer. It's still working.

Answer (score 6):

This can be used to "free" a database from client connections, so that you for example can rename it:

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(procpid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE datname='current_db';
ALTER DATABASE current_db RENAME TO old_db;
ALTER DATABASE new_db RENAME TO current_db;
```

Be aware that this might cause problematic behaviour to your client apps. Data actualy should not be currupted due to using transactions.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid)
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE pg_stat_activity.datname = 'db_name'
  AND pid <> pg_backend_pid();
```

This should work and your current connection should stay intact