# Postgres-9.1 having more Idle connections

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, process

The connections were created 2 days before. Can I kill the process manually by using the below query?

```
select pg_terminate_backend(procpid)
from pg_stat_activity
where datname = 'mydb'
and procpid <> pg_backend_pid()
and current_query = '<IDLE>'
and query_start < now() - INTERVAL '2880' MINUTE;
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: "Yes, sure you *can*." But I doubt you wanted to ask that.

Obviously, you need to make sure you only kill processes that need killing.
If possible, it's best done with the same role as the targeted processes to avoid collateral damage - only superusers can terminate processes of other roles.

Related:

- [How do I detach all other users from a postgres database?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6122/how-do-i-detach-all-other-users-from-a-postgres-database/6126#6126)